# Close vote test / audit questions and filters

Tags: discussion, vote-to-close, review-audits

I'm trying to work my way through the close vote test queue with a filter of `[c]`, which is in essence my field of expertise. My knowledge of (e.g.) JavaScript, iOS etc is sufficiently limited that I'm probably not competent to vote on them anyway.

Occasionally I run into a review question tagged `c` which has nothing to do with C. This is normally a great indicator that the question is off-topic for SO (not just badly tagged); these are often tend to have a number of random tags attached to a poor question for wider exposure. Not a problem.

However, a fair number of these are review/audit questions. Up comes a question about (e.g.) Javascript, with a `[c]` tag apparently added. If one didn't recognise these as review questions, the appropriate action on *every one* would be 'edit' to remove the bogus tag (I've never seen a true `[c]` review question). Even if the question is so poor it should be closed, I often don't know that as I know little enough about the subject.

If one's not to hit edit, how is one meant to respond?

One [review question](https://stackoverflow.com/review/close/4318456) (the text of which I've now lost so this is from memory) said *"when I do X (plus code block the contents of which I don't understand), I get error Y (plus description of the error) - why does this happen?"*. The question may (or may not) have been a dumb one, I wouldn't know. However, in terms of presentation of the question it was ten times better than the average new C question posted here. On this basis I voted "leave open". Apparently this was wrong (the question had serious problems), and I got the 'stop' warning.

So, to my questions:

- If people are trying to work down the close vote queue in the area of
  the expertise, is it useful to present review questions which don't
  actually match the filter, and to artificially tag them so that they
  do?
- If so, what is the correct to deal with those one doesn't know about? Hit Skip? Hit Edit as if one was removing artificially introduced tag? Hit 'Leave Open' to give the benefit of the doubt?

Comment: If you hit edit you will pass the audit, so go for it. A question having 1 incorrect tag is certainly not reason enough to close it if it is otherwise a good question, and if you can't tell whether the question is good then skip.

Comment: The usual guidance is "if you don't know, **skip**". Truer words have rarely been spoken.